# rsync all directories that start with a specific digit

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, rsync

I have directory loaded with thousands of sub directories:

```
/home/tmp/
          1
          12
          123
          1234
          2345
          234
          3456
          345
          34
```

Each subdirectory in turn has hundreds of subdirectories that I want to rsync if the first level subdirectory matches...

What I need is a way to copy/rsync only the directories that start with a given digit [1-9]...

What I think I want is basically something that would allow me to use wild cards to match

```
rsync -rzvvhP remotehost:/home/tmp/1* /home/tmp/
```

I want rsync to sync up the

```
/home/tmp/1/
/home/tmp/12/
/home/tmp/123/
/home/tmp/1234/
```

directories and any child subdirectories they have but not any of the first level directories that start with a different digit...

```
/home/tmp/234/
/home/tmp/2345/
........./3*/
........./4*/ etc..
```

**What I've tried:**

```
rsync -rzvvhP --exclude='*' --include-from=1.txt remotehost:/home/tmp/ /home/tmp/
```

where 1.txt contains:

```
1
12
123
1234
```

When I do this with 2.txt though rsync still seems to run through all the directories that start with 1 and 3 etc...

How can I do this so that I can have one command to rsync only the directories that start with any given digit?

Comment: Why wouldn't `/home/tmp/1*` work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this for your wildcard:

```
/home/tmp/{1,12,123,1234}
```

The `{}` generates each of the comma separated options so is equivalent to this:

```
/home/tmp/1 /home/tmp/12 /home/tmp/123 /home/tmp/1234
```